# Trouble with for loop with 2D array in ruby

Tags: ruby, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have studied C++, Java and I am learning Ruby now. 
but It's hard to adapt to iteration in ruby for me yet.

```
n = 4
arys = Array.new(3, Array.new(n+1, 0))

for i in 1..2
    for j in 1..n
        arys[i][j] = (i-1)*n+j
    end
end

p arys
```

> output of above code is as below
>
> ```
> [[0, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> ```

I thought it is like code as below in C

```
for(int i = 1; i<=2; i++)
   for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
       arys[i][j] = (i-1)*n+j
```

> therefore, I expected the output will be like
>        `[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 5, 6, 7, 8]]`

what make the difference between above two codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the very initialization line for `arys` you actually have created *one* inner array, *referenced three times* by `arys` outermost array:

```
arys.map &:__id__
#⇒ [
#  [0] 28193580,
#  [1] 28193580,
#  [2] 28193580
# ]
```

`__id__` above states for [unique object identifier](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__).

To achieve the behaviour you expected, one should produce three different arrays, e.g.:

```
ary = Array.new(5, 0)
arys = 3.times.map { ary.dup }
```

Note `dup` above, that clones the object. Now we have three different objects (arrays)

```
arys.map &:__id__
#⇒ [
#  [0] 34739980,
#  [1] 34739920,
#  [2] 34739860
# ]
```

and your code will work as expected.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know that This was just duplicating single reference! Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan Indeed, I just wanted to make things as clear as possible, I corrected an answer to make `dup` not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take advantage of [`Array#new`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-c-new) with a block, and use below code:

```
arys = Array.new(3) {Array.new(n+1, 0)}
```

Here, we pass a block to outer array constructor so that we can create an array of size `n+1` and default element values of `0` for sub-arrays (as needed in your problem statement).

---

Also, if you wish to use something other than `for` loop, here is one variant that will have same output:

```
(1...arys.size).each do |i|
    (1..n).each do |j|
        arys[i][j] = (i-1)*n + j
    end
end
```

Note use of `...` in `1...arys.size` to use exclusive range.
`1...10` is equivalent of to `1..9`, in other words `(1..9).to_a == (1...10).to_a` will be `true`

Comment: You can omit `|i|` since the argument it is not used.

Comment: @Stefan danke sehr - I always miss finer details.

Comment: Gern geschehen ;-) BTW, *"whenever an index is accessed for first time"* is the way `Hash.new` works. `Array.new` creates its elements immediately.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks again. I have learned a lot with feedback like this and looking at answers of others.